# How to combine formulatext() and arrayformula()?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-arrayformula

I want to use formulatext() with arrayformula() :

```
=arrayformula(formulatext(A1:A10))
```

But The `arrayformula` doesn't work. It should output 10 rows but it only returns a single row output.

Is there anyway around to combine them ?

Comment: “The FORMULATEXT function returns a formula as a string.”; the string even includes the equal sign. Arrayformula, OTOH, expects to find an “array_formula”.  Your question would be more informative if you were to describe the formulas in A1:A10, and, in detail, what you are trying to achieve by combining arrayformula&formulatext.

Answer (score 0):

It would probably be easiest to just use `=iferror(formulatext(A1))` and fill the formula down.

The `formulatext()` function is not array enabled and will only return the formula in the top left cell of its parameter range, regardless of whether you are using an `arrayformula()` wrapper or not.

To get the formulas in a `A1:A10`, you will have to fill the formula down. To get them in one go, you would need a script.